# what does "It was far from the only move in his arsenal" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article about Michael Jordan, and at the part describing his jumping skill it went "Then he'd gently descend back to earth. It was far from the only move in his arsenal: for several years Jordan could move, pass, defend and dunk so much better than any other players that he took on a superhuman aura."

I`m not sure if I took the meaning of "It was far from the only move in his arsenal" correctly. Does that mean the jumping is just one of the many great plays M.J. is capable of?

Thank you for the help as always!

Comment: The idiom *it was far from the only...* means it was only one of many possibilities. So *It was only one of many possible moves in his arsenal*.

Comment: That totally cleared up my confusion. Thank you very much

Comment: Kind of a mixed metaphor, though. I would either say "only **weapon** in his arsenal" or "only move in his **repertoire**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ***[arsenal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arsenal)*** is a :

> - A stock of weapons.

and when used figuratively it means:

> - A store or supply: an arsenal of retorts.

(AHD)

In the article the term is used figuratively suggesting the wide variety of physical abilities he was able to perform.

Comment: I never saw the word used like this. thank you for the help any way!